# IIS Express Error 500.19 (0x80070003) cannot read config file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've been working on MVC 5 tutorial on my office machine. Everything work perfectly in that environment.

Recently I pulled the repository to my personal laptop and I get this error.

**IIS Express Error 500.19 (0x80070003) cannot read config file**

In the error page I see the following path to the config file:

**\?\D:\Dev\Personal\MvcMovie\src\MvcMovie\wwwroot\web.config**

Which is a correct path for my office machine, but wrong for the home environment.

Additional info:

Here are locations for the Visual Studio solution:

At the office
**D:\Dev\Personal\MvcMovie**

At home

**C:\Dev\Projects\MvcMovie**

I'm a newbie to a web development, so hopefully there is an easy way to solve the problem.

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Check if the IUSR and the app pool account both have permissions to read the folder.

Comment: The reason that I get the error is that there is no such path. I searched everywhere but couldn't find where is that incorrect path is referenced.

Answer (score 35):

I have resolved the problem deleting the directory ".vs" in the local directory of the project.
Note: the directory .vs is hidden from Windows, enables hidden files to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me. For some reason, this broke as soon as I installed some recent Windows updates.

Comment: TX!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 2 days!! 2 days!!!  i'm Crazy!  Thanks <3

Comment: Wow! thanks! I've seen some other threads with suggestions that weren't fixing the issue. Just to point out that you probably have to close solution and/or VS before deleting the folder because of some file locks.

Answer (score 12):

Turned out, IIS Express was pulling the old path from .vs/config/applicationhost.config file

Modifying the path to the current one has resolved the issue